# LWC map overflow with many markers

Tags: lightning-web-components, map, sfdc-styleguide

I added a map to the LWC component, but once I add many markers points it overflows and the page will be too long.
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the code for the component. It would be easier to figure out the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue in the LWC, and there is an idea to fix it.
So I had to remove the side pane and it works fine.